# Can I override Ext.id function?

Tags: extjs

Can I override function id in ext-all-debug ExtJS general folder? I want to override this function to a different Javascript folder. How do I define?

```
id: function (el, prefix) {
        var me = this,
            sandboxPrefix = '';
        el = Ext.getDom(el, true) || {};
        if (el === document) {
            el.id = me.documentId;
        }
        else if (el === window) {
            el.id = me.windowId;
        }
        if (!el.id) {
            if (me.isSandboxed) {
                if (!me.uniqueGlobalNamespace) {
                    me.getUniqueGlobalNamespace();
                }
                sandboxPrefix = me.uniqueGlobalNamespace + '-';
            }
            el.id = sandboxPrefix + (prefix || "ext-gen") + (++Ext.idSeed);
        }
        return el.id;
    },
```

Comment: That function is not part of my ext-all-debug.js. Where did you find it?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Do you want to change prefix or what?

Comment: I want to change auto id definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with use of

> Ext.override

In the following fiddle, you can see "Custom Function called" in the console as id function has been overridden.

POC Code:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.override(Ext, {
        id: function (el, prefix) {
            console.log("Custom Function called");
            var me = this,
                sandboxPrefix = '';
            el = Ext.getDom(el, true) || {};
            if (el === document) {
                el.id = me.documentId;
            } else if (el === window) {
                el.id = me.windowId;
            }
            if (!el.id) {
                if (me.isSandboxed) {
                    sandboxPrefix = Ext.sandboxName.toLowerCase() + '-';
                }
                el.id = sandboxPrefix + (prefix || "ext-gen") + (++Ext.idSeed);
            }
            return el.id;
        }
    });


    Ext.application({
        name: 'Fiddle',

        launch: function () {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2cgq

Comment: I am taking "Cannot read property '$className' of underfined"  error for this function;

override: function(cls, overrides) {
            if (cls.prototype.$className) {
                return cls.override(overrides);
            }
            else {
                Ext.apply(cls.prototype, overrides);
            }
        }